# Android How to call methods from my DAO through Service using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, database, service, android-asynctask, dao

In my app, I use Service and need to call my DAO methods for CRUD operations.. In my DAO there are several methods..
These methods must be called an AsyncTask, but my question is how to call the methods of my DAO's without having to create an AsyncTask for each method of the my DAO?

E.g: i need call DAO methods in AsyncTask in this sequence:

```
MyService -> MyDAO.getAll()
MyService -> MyDAO.insertItem()
MyService -> MyDAO.deleteItem()
```

Is there any pattern to do this? or best practices ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a IntentService that is a special kind of service that runs outside the U.I. thread (just like an AsyncTask), so you can use the DAO without problems.

You can also create and start a normal java thread inside your Service, and do all your background processing on there, and then call the service stopSelf() from the thread when it dies.